# Why do two interpreter give results different from each other?

Tags: python, matlab

I'm implementing a numerical method in Matlab. But there' something wrong with my formula or Matlab seems fool. I'd like to get 1920 in Matlab But the result is as follow. python interpreter gives

```
>>> x0_square = 3200
>>> x0 = 2560
>>> scale_factor = 2048
>>> x = 2048
>>> a = x0_square +  ( ( (2 * x0) * (x - x0) ) / scale_factor)
>>> print a
1920
```

But Matlab gives

```
% all variables here is int16. all value are the same as the above.
>> x_square_a = int16(x0_square +  ( ( (2 .* x0) .* (x - x0) ) ./ scale_factor));
>> x_square_a

x_square_a =

   3184
```

Why do they give different results? How can I get 1920 from Matlab interpreter? Also, I'm under constraint that any variable can't be used except int16.

Comment: You're more likely the fool, not Matlab.  I'm guessing that you've been bitten by a poor understanding of integer division.

Comment: Python doesn't have the type coercion thing I've temporarily forgotten the name of. `a = (int)(x0_square +  ( ( (2 * x0) * (x - x0) ) / scale_factor))` makes no sense. You want `int((x0_square +  ( ( (2 * x0) * (x - x0) ) / scale_factor)))` (although this may not be the only problem).

Comment: But you are using several variables: `>>> x0_square = 3200
>>> x0 = 2560
>>> scale_factor = 2048` assignes 3 variables. Do you mean functions or something?

Comment: @duffymo; The Python code work the same in Python 3 without integer division. // @user2387370; Actually that doesn't change anything as `(int)` just results in `int`.

Comment: corrected my question.

Comment: @Veedrac Oh right, the parens after. I just saw `(int)` and assumed they were trying something like `(int)"7"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `int16` in Matlab. Python's integers are of unlimited precision and thus will not overflow. If you use `numpy.int16` liberally in the Python code you get

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in short_scalars
```

so this is definitely an overflow problem.

---

A solution in Python using `numpy.int16`s is to move the division earlier on:

```
x0_square = int16(3200)
x0 = int16(2560)
scale_factor = int16(2048)
x = int16(2048)
a = int16(x0_square +  ( ( (int16(2) * x0)  / scale_factor * (x - x0) )))
a
#>>> 1920
```

So that suggests the matlab code should be

```
x_square_a = int16(x0_square +  ( ( (2 .* x0) ./ scale_factor .* (x - x0) )));
```

Comment: +1 - Second data point from you telling me that you know more than a little about numerical methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just did the calculation by hand with an HP calculator; it confirms that you ought to get 1920.

The value `2*2,560*(2,048-2,560) = -1,310,720`.  The biggest 16-bit integer is `2^16 = 65,536`.

Veedrac has hit it on the head - overflow.  Try 32 bit integers.